# Outlook 2007 "delivery notification was not sent by the destination"

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange-2010

A single user is getting this error

```
Delivery to these recipients or distribution lists is complete, but delivery notification was not sent by the destination:

Recipient Name

Subject: Email Subject
```

For almost every message sent in outlook 2007. No other users get this and Read recpiets and delivery receipts are disabled.

Anyone know how to stop these messages for this user?

Comment: Are you forwarding any email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually reinstalled outlook which fixed it.